# android alarms: Can alarm receiver cancel alarm after X repeats /

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

My android app allows the user to select an item and set an alarm on it. I'm trying to implement this with a repeating alarm, but I don't want the alarm to repeat forever. I want it to automatically be cancelled after 2 repeats. For example, the user selects an item and sets the alarm to 30 minutes. Thirty minutes later the alarm goes off (notification is delivered), but the user hasn't taken any action other than silence the alarm. Five minutes later the alarm is repeated if the user hasn't taken any action on the selected item. Another five minutes later the alarm is repeated if the user still hasn't taken any action.

If it gets to the second reminder, regardless of whether the user takes action or not, I'd
like to cancel the alarm.

I'm pretty sure I can manage this outside of alarm receiver class, but is there a way
within the class to determine how many times the alarm for a specific item has been
called ? My alarm receiver class extends Service.

Thanks,
-Mar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple and use a SharedPreference to store this counter. Increment on the alarm and then reset it when the alarm is set again.

Comment: Donn, I really like the idea of using SharedPreferences. Thanks for the suggestion. If I understand you, the alarm receiver will use a SharedPrefence entry as a counter. I still have one technical question. Let's say the user selects item_AA and sets its alarm to 25 minutes. Then a few minutes later the user selects item_CC and sets its alarm to 25 minutes. In this case it seems I would need two SharedPrefence counters, one for item_AA and one for item_CC...but within the alarm receiver how can I tell which counter to reference ?

Comment: Correct, you will need a unique name for each alarm. Passing that around in the PendingIntent might do the trick.